# Prove that some vectors are linearly dependent if and only if there are nontrivial relations among them?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I don't really understand this proof given from the textbook:

Suppose some vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are linearly dependent and this $v_i$ is a redundant vector. $$v_i = c_1*v_1 +\cdots+c_{i-1}*v_{i-1}$$ Hence, $$-v_i + c_1*v_1+\cdots+c_{i-1}*v_{i-1} = 0$$

How exactly does this prove that $c_1*v_1+\cdots+c_m*v_m = 0$?

Comment: Why do  you think this is a proof that $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_m v_m = 0$? What does that even mean, when you haven't said what $c_m$ could be? I think you are leaving out some very important step(s) of the proof in what you are telling us, and without those steps of course it doesn't make sense.

Comment: In fact, you start by supposing that the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are linearly dependent _and_ that $v_i$ is redundant--so haven't you just presupposed _both_ sides of the "if and only if"? Maybe you should go back to the textbook and carefully examine the proof; it seems very unlikely that it is anything like what you say here.

Comment: @DavidK This is exactly what the textbook says. I don't see the problem, as linear dependence is the same thing as having a $v_i$ being redundant.

Comment: I think the source of confusion here (my confusion, at least!) is that you did not clearly state what was known and what was to be proved. I suppose "has a redundant vector" _could_ be someone's definition of linear dependence, but I would have expected linear dependence to be defined by the existence of a non-trivial relation $c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_m v_m = 0$ over all of the vectors, so that the "only if" part follows by definition. What's missing here is the context of what the book said _before_ the four quoted lines and what it said afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c_i=-1$, as you can see just by subtracting $v_i$ from both sides...
Just set $c_j=0$ for $j\gt i$...

Note:  just *one* $c_k$ need be nonzero...

I.e.  a *nontrivial* linear combination of the $v_1,\dots,v_m$ has been found which equals zero.  It's nontrivial since $c_i=-1\not =0$...

Comment: yes but you will still get $c_m*v_m$ term leftover, hence it is not 0

Comment: Take all $c_j=0$ for $j\gt i$.  Good point.  I will edit...

Comment: Ah I see! I missed the fact that you only need one non-zero term for a nontrivial solution

Comment: @Goldname Nice catch .. .